# P-FET not shutting off

Tags: mosfet, switches, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

I am using the [BSH203,215](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/nexperia-usa-inc/BSH203-215/1155061) to connect/disconnect power to an RFM69 chip shown in the configuration below.

My problem is that when I drive the gate of the FET high (RFM_EN) using the microcontroller, I am still getting ~1V on the 3V3_RFM line.

I am not sure why this is the case though, I think I should be getting ~0 V.

Am I doing something wrong here?

[image]

Comment: What is the gate voltage? Is SPI being disabled too?

Comment: the gate voltage gets pulled up to 3.3V to disable. The SPI is not active during this time either.

Comment: @RGBEngineer, if the pins of RFM module have ESD diodes to  it's supply then, you cannot pull any pin high when 3.3V is cut-off. The pull-up on NSS can be causing this and other spi pins can cause this  if they are being driven high

Comment: Maybe there is a bright light shining on the green LED causing it to be a solar panel?

Comment: I can't tell if this is a joke, but I will investigate that as well.

Comment: @Audioguru Hah, a rather far-out possibility (it's probably <1uA), but one nonetheless. And yes, inactive in the sense of all lines being hi-Z or pulled low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R306 should be connected to 3V3_RFM. All other connections from the micro should be set to zero volts.

Current is passing through the protection diodes of the RFM 69 to pin 11.

The P-FET is probably ok.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, double (and triple) check the pinout. Get another BSH203 part and check it with a multimeter in diode mode to verify the direction of the diode. Then make sure it's in the right way on the board.

If it's in the right direction then check the gate voltage relative to the source voltage (use a meter and measure the voltage between G and S) and verify that it really is not being pulled down (0V should be off).